# C++ How to prevent child process binding port after fork() on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I have a "launcher" programs that listens to port X, and then starts other processess with fork()

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    a.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
        if(bind(os,(struct sockaddr *)&a,sizeof(a)) == -1) {
            if(Debug){
            printf("Launher: Can't bind our address (%s)\n", argv[1]);
        }
            exit(1); 
        }
```

Fork:

```
 int pid = fork();
        if ( pid == 0 ) 
        {
            execl( "udp-proxy/udp_proxy","udp-proxy/udp_proxy",listenPort.c_str(),listenClient.c_str(),listenHost.c_str(),nullptr );
        }
```

However, afrer I restart the "launcher", it shows a message: "Launher: Can't bind our address".

I checked with "lsof -i UDP", and it seems that child processes are listening to this port, so it can't be binded again.
Is it possible to prevent child process using the same binded sockets? I read something about "file descriptors" but I don't know how to prevent it :(

Comment: Do the child processes need that socket at all? Can you just use `SOCK_CLOEXEC`?

Comment: No, they don't need it. But where exactly should I set the SOCK_CLOEXEC flag? In the parent or in the child process?

Comment: On Linux, see `man 2 socket`: http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket

Comment: It doesn't really matter when you set it, but it's much, MUCH easier to set CLOEXEC whenever you create a file descriptor.

Comment: Thank you, I just changed uint32_t os=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_IP); to: uint32_t os=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC,IPPROTO_IP);
And now it works as expected :)

Comment: You should use `int` instead of `uint32_t`.  Remember that `socket()` can return -1.

Comment: You may post the solution as an actual answer :-) Don't include the answer in the question. This would make it more visible and will help others find it more easily.

Comment: I will, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dietrich Epp for solution.

Adding SOCK_CLOEXEC flag fixes the problem.

Before:

```
int os=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_IP);
```

After:

```
int os=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC,IPPROTO_IP);
```